# What's the difference between State, IntegerState, ExplicitIntegerState and ImplicitIntegerState?

Tags: design-patterns, uml, state-pattern

I'm familiar with the [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern), but recently I've heard about the three other design patterns mentioned in the title. I have no idea what distinguishes those three patterns from the normal state pattern, and Google also doesn't help!

---

UPDATE: I've originally found those patterns in the following graphic (headline: relationship between design patterns), but without any additional information about them:

[image: design patterns]

Comment: are your sure they are related to the State pattern, i have never heard of them either, can you tell where you have across them ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure they are related to it. I've updated my question and added the source where I found those patterns!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what seems to be the answer to your question but it is written in dutch which i believe won't be a problem for you. From what i was able to extract from the text, IntegerState and its two variants you have mentioned are used to implement State Machines or Automaton using integer constants instead of typical polymorphism, anyway i could be wrong because i don't understand dutch so here is the link to the [Lecture Note](http://st.inf.tu-dresden.de/files/teaching/ss11/swt/Vorlesungen/34-analysis-dynamic-modelling-lifecycles-2x2.pdf).